# Random links popping up virus on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, popups

Since I visited the site from chrome http://www.computerworld.com/article/2536806/networking/10-killer-texting-tricks.html and clicked on skip ad a window popped in background. I didn't notice that.So it was running for like 20 minutes and when I closed chrome I saw it running. I checked my history and there were sites i had never visited like joystamps.com and funpicplanet.com. I tried the malware bytes scan and nothing was found.

UPDATE 
After visiting http://www.computerworld.com/article/2536806/networking/10-killer-texting-tricks.html I saw this in my history.

[image]

[image: screenshot link.]

Answer (score 2):

You may have installed Google Chrome Extension (un)intentionally that has History API Access.

With chrome History permission you can do all sort of stuffs with History : [History API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history)

Check for Chrome Extensions(chrome://extensions in Chrome Browser) Page and disable one of such extensions

Hope that would be helpful.

Thanks !!